# Is there a link between ‘Kill the Moon’ and ‘The Beast Below’?

Tags: doctor-who

After watching this last episode it immediately came to mind that

> the creature at the end

is similar to the star-whale that appears in Matt Smith's episode 'The Beast Below'.

Does anyone know if these are actually the same creatures?

Comment: It was more like a butterfly than a whale, but who knows. Some writer could come up with that some time in the future...I don't think this will get a right answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems incredibly unlikely, considering that no connections between the two creatures were made or implied in the episode, and given the fact that the Star Whale was pink:

[image]

And had no wings:

[image]

Whereas the creature that hatched from the moon was purple and had four very large wings:

[image]

Comment: Plus the Doctor did seem to think that the moon creature was unique, the only one of its kind. (Which presumably means that we finally have a definitive answer that the egg came first, not the chicken.)

Comment: Agree with @Paul; the whale might have been the last of its kind, but at one point there were many of them. The moon-creature seems to be a singular entity. (...that lays an egg which presumably does not require fertilization immediately after hatching. Kind of like a tribble. Moon-sized tribbles sound utterly horrifying.)

Comment: @BrianS Horrifying for the Klingons, at least.

Comment: A pink creature viewed through the blueness of the sky might well appear purple.

Comment: Plot twist, it's not his final form :P

Answer (score 1):

The "connection" is more just a common theme on Doctor Who - big scary things are not always monsters, and are not always out to kill us.

They are not the same creature, but the lesson is the same - we don't always have to shoot (or enslave) the big scary thing. Sometimes they're here to help, and sometimes they're just passing through.